# Best way to achieve fluid animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to apply little tricky fluid ink animation as same as the below image:

[image]

I want to achieve using the basic classes only like applying scale, translate etc. I don't want to go with 2D or 3D. As I have checked some of the links they are suggesting frame animation but It doesn't have smooth transition.

Kindly suggest best way to achieve this animation.

Thanks,

Comment: There are [third party libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2932) that achieve this, I'd suggest looking at some of the [available libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111) in detail

Comment: @EdGeorge : Sounds great! But I want to understand the basic motion with core animations. If you could explain in brief for the same that would be great!

Comment: Core Animations is an iOS/OSX library and not related to Android. If you want to see how to achieve it in Android, see the GitHub of the project I linked. You can try and understand how it achieves the effect from there

Answer (score 2):

"I don't want to go with 2D or 3D."

Well.. I don't know about you but those are the only options until we have 4D screens and mindsets.

But I guess you mean using 2D images or 3D models.

Unless you want to procedurally generate that (which can be quite a pain) I'd suggest using a spritesheet, there may be better ways to do this but I think a spritesheet on 30fps might be the easiest + fluid way to do this, increase FPS to increase fluidness (until the max of androids 60 fps screens)

Basically:

Create a (example) 256x128 sprite, and "manually" animate the sphere to the other side of the image, saving each "frame" and either create 1 big texture with all the frames (most efficient) or save each frame independently (lower on RAM if you manage it well, but it'll be hard to get 60 fps with this due to loading times)

Comment: It would be very difficult to achieve using spritesheet, I dont think the same smoothness and efficiency would be there but yeah I could try! If you could help with any sample! Or let's think if atleast we have any option using 2D images or 3D models!

Comment: I think then using an animated mesh might be best.. Which I forgot to mention in my original reply. However using 3D in a mostly 2D or UI oriented app might get a bit annoying to properly get right..

Comment: If you could please provide any example?

Comment: any example like this

Answer (score 2):

You can check the recently announced [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) library (by Airbnb).
It is a library for Android that parses Adobe After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin (related project) and renders them natively on Android devices.

Comment: This answer would be better if you showed how the fluid animation could be achieved with Lottie